# Reading file.Regular Expressions

Tags: powershell

There is a file C: \ Density.txt, in which four values ​​are periodically written.
For processing and further analysis, I need only the fourth sign, Density:.

The file processing approach is as follows.
 is there a possibility to get the Density: value using regular expressions?

File example English:

```
Solid density
Mass in the air:
           23.384 (1) g
Mass in liquid:
           23.383 (3) g
Solid volume:
               0.001 cm3
 
  Density:
          1111.586 g / cm3
           ==============
Solid density
Mass in the air:
           23.384 (1) g
Mass in liquid:
           23.383 (3) g
Solid volume:
               0.001 cm3
 
  Density:
          1112.586 g / cm3
           ==============
Solid density
Mass in the air:
           23.384 (1) g
Mass in liquid:
           23.383 (3) g
Solid volume:
               0.001 cm3
 
  Density:
          1113.586 g / cm3
           ==============
```

I Try to add your solution code, but resive an error. I need to lock the files (ScalesM) for writing and reading.Having obtained the Values, I need to write the result line by line into the other file OutFile. Is any way to adap your solution code?

```
$ScalesM = [System.io.File]::Open('C:\DensityNT.txt', 'Open', 'ReadWrite', 'None') 
$OutFile = [System.io.File]::Open('C:\\InfinityDensity.txt', 'append', 'Write', 'None')

            $ScalesM2 = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($ScalesM)
            $text = $text + $ScalesM2.ReadToEnd()
  # Next sring Give my the Error -
$text = ($text | Select-String -Pattern "[0-9\.].+?(?=( g\/cm3))" -AllMatches).Matches.Value 

            $data = $enc.GetBytes($text) 
            $OutFile.write($data,0,$data.length) 


            $ScalesM.SetLength(0)
            $ScalesM.Close()
            $OutFile.Close()
```

Comment: A RegEx with lookarounds: `(Get-Content .\Density.txt | Select-String '(?<=^\s+)[\d\.]+(?= g \/ cm3)').Matches.Value`

Comment: Hi everybody! Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$txt = Get-Content 'PATH TO THE DENSITY.TXT FILE'
$regex = [regex] '(?m)Density:\s+(?<density>.+)'
$match = $regex.Match($txt)
while ($match.Success) {
    $match.Groups['density'].Value
    $match = $match.NextMatch()
}
```

will output

> ```
> 1111.586 g / cm3
> 1112.586 g / cm3
> 1113.586 g / cm3
> ```

---

**Update**

On my machine a regex with value `Плотность:` did not work.
As the values you want are the ones ending in `g/cm3` or `g / cm3`, the code below gets them for both the English and the Russian language versions:

```
$txt = Get-Content 'PATH TO THE DENSITY.TXT FILE' -Encoding UTF8
$regex  = [regex]'(?<density>\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s+g\s*/\s*cm3)'
$match = $regex.Match($txt)
$result = while ($match.Success) {
    $match.Groups['density'].Value
    $match = $match.NextMatch()
} 

# output on screen:
$result

# output to file
$result | Set-Content 'D:\Densities.txt'
```

Regex details:

> ```
> (?<density>     Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “density”
>    \d           Match a single digit 0..9
>       +         Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>    (?:          Match the regular expression below
>       \.        Match the character “.” literally
>       \d        Match a single digit 0..9
>          +      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>    )?           Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>    \s           Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
>       +         Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>    g            Match the character “g” literally
>    \s           Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
>       *         Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>    \/           Match the character “/” literally
>    \s           Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
>       *         Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>    cm3          Match the characters “cm3” literally
> )
> ```

Comment: Is there a way to add processing to another language?

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиминов Difficult to say what you mean.. Do you mean the label `Density` could be in a different language? If so, just change `Density:` into `[Regex]::Escape(WHATEVER THE WORD YOU SEEK MIGHT BE)`. Can you give an example?

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиминов I have updated my answer and tested with your Russian example file. On my machine (Dutch Windows 7 Pro) it works. Can you test it please?

Comment: Thank you for update. I need to lock files via [System.io.File]::Open. I added update to first/top message. I Try to lock file and then read and get 4th value and write the result to OutFile via [System.io.File]::Open. 

I Try to do the action in one transaction

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиминов I may be wrong, but to my understanding the `Get-Content` cmdlet already locks the file while reading..

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиминов `$result` is simply an array of strings. If all you want is the **last** entry for density in the file, you can use the `-1` index on the `$result` array and save only that value. `$result[-1] | Set-Content 'D:\Densities.txt'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use positive lookahead:

```
$Text = Get-Content C:\Density.txt
($Text | Select-String -Pattern "[0-9\.].+?(?=( g \/ cm3))" -AllMatches).Matches.Value
```

Output:

```
1111.586 
1112.586 
1113.586
```

Comment: I Try to add your solution code, but resive an error. I need to lock the files (ScalesM) for writing and reading.Having obtained the Values, I need to write the result line by line into the other file OutFile. Is any way to adap your solution code? add new code to the TOP

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for help.
Complete resolution below:

```
$TValue = ""
$enc    = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$NL     = [System.Environment]::NewLine

while ($countI=1) {

try {
    $ScalesM = [System.io.File]::Open('C:\IN.txt', 'Open', 'ReadWrite', 'None') 
    $OutFile = [System.io.File]::Open('C:\OUT.txt', 'append', 'Write', 'None')

    $ScalesM2 = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($ScalesM)
    $text = $ScalesM2.ReadToEnd()

         [regex]::matches($text, ':\s*(\d+\.?\d*)\s+g\s*/\s*cm3') | %{
        $TValue = $TValue +  $_.Groups[1].value + $NL
                                                                  }

        $data = $enc.GetBytes($TValue) 
        $OutFile.write($data,0,$data.Length)
        $ScalesM.SetLength(0) 
        $ScalesM.Close()
        $OutFile.Close()

        Wait-Event -Timeout 1

    }

catch {
    echo ″Some error was found.″
            $ScalesM.Close()
            $OutFile.Close()
    Wait-Event -Timeout 0.5
}

}
```